# Is there an node like statement available in mongodb

Tags: regex, mongodb, filter, aggregate-functions, sql-like

I want to filter the decimal value in child array of json file.In below sample code i want to apply the like function to get the json value like(t1,t2) in below sample file.

Sample code:

```
db.getCollection('temp').find({},{"temp.text./.*t.*/.value":1})
```

Sample Json file:

```
{
    "_id" :0"),     
    "temp" : {
        "text" : {
            "t1" : {

                "value" : "960"
            },
            "t2" : {                               
                "value" : "959"
            },
            "t3" : {                
                "value" : "961"
            },
            "t4" : {               
                "value" : "962"
            },
            "t5" : {                               
                "value" : "6.0"
            }

        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't have a way to filter field names directly other than projection, which is exact match only.

However, using aggregation you can use $objectToArray, which would convert the object `{"t1" : {"value" : "960"}}` to `[{"k":"t1","v":{"value":"960"}}]`.  You can then filter based on the value of `k`, and use $arrayToObject to convert the entries left back into an object.

```
.aggregate([
    {$addFields:{
          "temp.text":{
               $arrayToObject:{
                    $filter:{
                        input:{$objectToArray:"$temp.text"},
                        cond:{
                              $regexMatch:{
                                   input:"$$this.k",
                                   regex:/t/
                              }
                        }             
                    }
               }
          }
    }}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fzmDCGJd3qj)

Comment: I want to apply where in aggregate  it throw error"failed"sample codeaggregate([{_id : "0322",snapshot: "Symbol"},
    {$addFields:{
          "temp.text":{
               $arrayToObject:{
                    $filter:{
                        input:{$objectToArray:"$temp.text"},
                        cond:{
                              $regexMatch:{
                                   input:"$$this.k",
                                   regex:/t/
                              }
                        }             
                    }
               }
          }
    }}
])

Comment: It's a little hard to see in comment format, I think you are missing the `$match` keyword, like `{$match: {_id : "0322",snapshot: "Symbol"}}`